# How to render an frontend image in backend using Yii2 DetailView?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to render/show an image in a view on **backend**, but the image location is in `frontend/web/uploads`.

I tried doing this on the `DetailView::widget()`:

```php
...
[
    'attribute'=>'image',
    'value'=>('/frontend/web/uploads/'.$model->image),
    'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],
```

But the image is not showing up. Any help?

Comment: Check your image location is correct and also check your generated html using inspect element for image tag.

Comment: @InsaneSkull, thanks for your response, i have check my image location and the existence. of the image, and there is no problem,   i get 'could not load image ' from  using inspect element

Comment: is possible to call the image from the backend/view/register/view.php  and my image location in the frontend/web/uploads

Comment: Please share your URL managers configs. And show how frontend and backend URLs looks like.

Comment: @rob006, this my url manager `'urlManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlManager',
            
            'showScriptName' => false,
          
            'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
            'rules' => array(
                    '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
                    '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            ),
        ],` and i use virtual host form my frontend (repasca.devs) and for my backend (admin.repasca.devs)

Comment: Edit your question and add this config to your question - it is unreadable in comments. Do you have only one URL manager without separation between frontend and backend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the only place where you're linking to frontend from backend, the easiest way would be defining alias in your backend config:

```
Yii::setAlias('@frontendUploads', 'https://repasca.devs/uploads');
```

And use this alias for building file URL:

```
[
    'attribute' => 'image',
    'value' => Yii::getAlias('@frontendUploads') . '/' . $model->image,
    'format' => ['image', ['width' => '100', 'height' => '100']],
],
```

Comment: i'am sory, i am new with yii2, in backend config folder there are many file , where i put this `Yii::setAlias('@frontendUloads', 'https://repasca.devs/uploads');`?

Comment: In `backend/config/bootstrap.php` (assuming that you're using advanced template).

Comment: Make sure that you don't have any typo and `backend/config/bootstrap.php` is loaded in your app. You may also try moving `Yii::setAlias('@frontendUploads', 'https://repasca.devs/uploads');` into `common/config/bootstrap.php` - maybe you're using it in non-backend application.

Comment: moving `Yii::setAlias('@frontendUploads', 'http://repasca.devs/uploads'); `into common/config/bootstrap.php solved the problem, thanks you

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible to access `frontend/web/uploads` to `backend` view.

First add `urlManagerFrontend` in `backend->config->main.php` like

```
'components' => [
    'urlManagerFrontend' => [
        'class' => 'yii\web\urlManager',
        'baseUrl' => 'frontend/web/', //Access frontend web url
    ],
],
```

And then access the `frontend/web/` to the `backend` like

```
Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->baseUrl.'/uploads/your_image.jpg'
```

In DetailView::widget like

```
[
   'attribute'=>'image',
   'value'=> function ($model) {
        return Html::img(Yii::$app->urlManagerFrontend->baseUrl.'/uploads/'.$model->image, ['alt' => 'No Image', 'width' => '10px', 'height' => '10px']);
   },
   'format' => 'raw',
],
```

Comment: @eniac05 if this answer helpful for you then please accept by clicking right sign. because it is help to another one.

Comment: thanks for your respons, but that not work, image still not show just showing 'no image', i have check with inspect elemen the result like this  `<img src="frontend/web/uploads/foto_2_cow2.jpg" alt="No Image" width="10px" height="10px">`

Comment: this is work for me. what is your problem. please show in browser console any error given or not ?

Comment: in inspect element if i change the source like this`<img alt="No Image" src="http://repasca.devs/uploads/foto_2_cow2.jpg" width="10px" height="10px">` the image finaly show, http://repasca.devs is my virtual host to call frontend web